# Outlook for Mac 2011: lost folders "On my computer"

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

My MacBook pro shut down due to low battery while I was using outlook for Mac 2011. When I recharged and rebooted all the "on my computer" folders disappeared. I have time machine back ups but do not know how to find and restore the lost folders.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, Outlook stores the files in:

`~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Database`
`~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Data Records`

If you want to restore from your Time Machine backup, the best way I find is:

First rename `Microsoft User Data` to `Microsoft User Data.old` in your Documents folder.(You always want a backup in case something goes wrong)

Then navigate to:

`YOUR TIME MACHINE HDD/Backups.backupdb/YOUR COMPUTER NAME/Latest/Macintosh HD/Users/Username/Documents/` and drag the `Microsoft User Data` folder to the same location on your computer's HDD. (you can replace `Latest` with an earlier dated folder if needed.)

Reopen Outlook and see if everything is there.

You could also use the Time Machine interface to do this but I find it clunky. I always like to restore single files using the steps above.